# Need Clear explanation for CHtml::dropDownList() method in yii

Tags: yii

**public static function dropDownList($name,$select,$data,$htmlOptions=array())**

In this above syntax i not able to understand ***$select*** field.In yii tutorial(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail) they are said $select is selected item.but i cant able to understand.can anyone give clear example with  explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a dropdown list with the following values

```
$daysOfTheWeek = array(
    0 => 'Monday',
    1 => 'Tuesday',
    2 => 'Wednesday'
    3 => 'Thursday'
);
```

Then if you want at the beging that the selected value is Tuesday then in the widget you will put:

```
CHtml::dropDownList('daysOfTheWeek', '0', $daysOfTheWeek);
```

This is usefull when you want to edit something, since it already has an assigned value you can put it by default so the dropdown will be already filled with the previous value.